# How long is it supposed to take "creating a persistant file" with Universal USB Installer?

Tags: system-installation, usb, files, persistence

> Creating a persistent file. Progress will not move until finished...

It's been at it for 3-4 hours. I selected to install Ubuntu on a near empty drive (With just the image file of the OS installer in it.

I'm not sure if I did something wrong, or if something went wrong on the other end, or both (or is this supposed to be normal?)

I'm a Windows refugee. System specs are 16GB RAM, i7-7700K (2.80GHz), GTX 1050 Ti.

Comment: 3-4 hours is way too much even in a slow computer. Please specify your computer's brand name and model. -- You could also try `mkusb`, which creates a `casper-rw` *partition* instead of such a file for persistence. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent

Comment: Just updated with specs. 16GB RAM/i7-7700K/GTX 1050 Ti. Model is Dell 15 7567

Comment: My experience (with a Dell Latitude E7240) is that it works well with Ubuntu. Something else is the problem, maybe the iso file (did you check it with md5sum?, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes), maybe the tool (Universal USB Installer). -- You will probably need the boot option `nomodeset` to get the nvidia graphics work in a [persistent] live drive. If you create an installed system in your USB drive, you can also install a proprietary nvidia driver (to improve the performance), but it will reduce the portability between computers.

Comment: Or maybe you have an extremely slow USB pendrive. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed

Comment: Is it safe to force abort this installation before I can try troubleshooting this? (I won't blame you if something goes wrong, just need your opinion)

Comment: I think the Universal USB Installer writes only to the USB pendrive, and it should be overwritten anyway, so I think it is safe to  force abort this installation. -- Are you installing from Windows or from Linux?

Comment: Windows 10. There's two drives, an SSD and a HDD. The OS (C:) for W10 is in the SSD while the HDD was empty (Save for the iso Ubuntu installer). I figured I'd install the OS in the HDD.

Comment: Then you can download an image file (.img) with mkusb and clone it with Win32DiskImager to the drive where you want the installer. See the following links, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Compressed_image_file_with_a_persistent_live_system and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/compressed-image_2_USB-or-SD. This works to USB drives, I don't know if Win32DiskImager will write to an internal drive (or SSD via USB). mkusb can do it, but it is a linux tool, does not work in Windows. Have you got a USB pendrive?

Comment: I have a 4GB USB pen drive here.

Comment: I think I know what went wrong. It was my fault. Universal USB asked me (optional) to define the persistent data size and I accidentally had the whole space drive (of the HDD) defined for it, rather than a small number like 2GB. Maybe that's why it was taking forever?

edit: I retried the install. This time it wrapped up under 10 seconds! That must have been it.

Comment: I think you are right, and that you solved your problem. Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Universal USB Installer and a `casper-rw` file

The OP, @Bonita, was able to solve the problem after we had exchanged ideas via comments. I write this answer to explain the solution.

The Universal USB Installer creates a `casper-rw` file for persistence, and she had selected all remaining space for it, which made it huge, because it was in a hard disk drive. The method to create the `casper-rw` file is intended for rather small USB pendrives, and it will take a very long time for a huge file.

**She solved the problem by creating a smaller `casper-rw` file, only a few Gigabyte.**

> Universal USB asked me (optional) to define the persistent data size
>   and I accidentally had the whole space drive (of the HDD) defined for
>   it, rather than a small number like 2GB. Maybe that's why it was
>   taking forever? edit: I retried the install. This time it wrapped up
>   under 10 seconds! That must have been it.

### `mkusb` and a `casper-rw` partition

If you have a big USB drive, like in this case a hard disk drive, or an SSD, and you want to use all the remaining drive space for persistence, you can use a persistent live system with a `casper-rw` partition.

[`mkusb`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can create such a [persistent live](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) system, and setting up a big or huge partition is much faster than doing it for a file of the same size.

### General discussion

See also this link, and the discussion in the whole thread (the question and also the other answers),

[... try out new OS releases without committing to it? - USB alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012717/what-is-a-cheap-simple-way-to-try-out-new-os-releases-without-committing-to-it/1012752#1012752)

Answer (score 1):

As an aside - in windows 10 the casper-rw file is created in your Users\"user name"\AppData\Local\Temp folder before being deleted at the end of the process.  If (as I have just done) you have a larger USB drive (128GB) and you set the persistent file size too big you may find yourself running out of space on your OS drive (in my case a 258GB NVME).  This will slow/stop the process and can cause a significant problems in win 10 and if you are forced to abort the process you will need to find the file and delete it to get your space back.

Comment: Also on Windows 7.  I found it (and various other files) in a subfolder of the `TEMP` directory with a name `nst22C.tmp` (I expect the name will always begin `nst...`).  The persistent file creation does indeed appear to hang if it runs out of space on the drive with your `TEMP` directory - and the progress dialog changes from showing progress to a message like "24501+0 records out".